# How to reuse subquery in select clause?

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery, lateral-join

I'd like to be able to reuse a subquery in my select without having to type it all out again. Is there a way to do this?

For example the first item in the select is a subquery that returns a NAME.

In the second select item I'd like to reuse the "NAME" subquery without having to type it out again.

I looked at CTEs but I couldn't see how you'd pass in a parameter for the where clause. In this example I need to access T1.ID from the main query in the subquery but I didn't see a way to to this with a CTE.

```
SELECT

(SELECT NAME FROM TABLE2 T2 WHERE T2.ID=T1.ID) AS NAME,

(SELECT STATE FROM TABLE3 T3 WHERE T3.NAME=(SELECT NAME FROM TABLE2 T2 WHERE T2.ID=T1.ID)) AS STATE

FROM TABLE1 T1
```

Comment: You cannot.  It is a correlated subquery.

Comment: WHy can't you `join` `t2` on `t1` using `ID` then `t3` on `t2` using `name`, then do `SELECT t2.Name, t3.State` ?

Comment: @Gordon: I'm leaning towards your answer. The other answers would mean I'd have to restructure the whole query and I'm not sure that's even possible. My actual query is pretty complicated, I just made up an easy example for this question.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a typical use case for a lateral join. In TSQL, you can use `outer apply`:

```
select t2.name, t3.state
from table1 t1
outer apply (select * from table2 t2 where t2.id   = t1.id  ) t2
outer apply (select * from table3 t3 where t3.name = t2.name) t3
```

Comment: Maybe I should have made my example a little more complicated. My actual subquery contains several joins and other logic. And the main query is also pretty complex. I just stripped out the complexity to make the question more straightforward. It would be difficult to restructure the whole query I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the joins would be evaluated as INNER JOIN.  This query should return the same output

```
SELECT T2.[NAME], T3.[STATE]
FROM TABLE1 T1
     join TABLE2 T2 on T2.ID=T1.ID
     join Table3 T3 on T2.[NAME]=T3.[NAME];
```